# Why do i add #4 to a regsiter to have the next iteration?

Tags: assembly, arm

in school we are learning assembly. I tried to study this code

```
RES:       .word 0
N:         .word 5
NUM1:      .word 3, -17, 27, -12, 322

LDR r1, N
ADR r2, NUM1
MOV r0, #0

LOOP:      LDR r3, [r2]
           ADD r0, r0, r3
           ADD r2, r2, #4
           SUB r1, r1, #1
           CMP r1, #0
           BGT LOOP
           STR r0, RES
```

But i dont understand this line `ADD r2, r2, #4` our teacher tell us this is for next iteration, but why it is not `ADD r2, r2, #1` ?

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?

Comment: I think it's ARM, x86 doesn't have `BGT`

Comment: @raspiduino I don't like to guess.  There could be other architectures with these mnemonics; they are all pretty generic.

Comment: I think add 4 because each value is 4 byte in length, so it will point to the next element

Comment: @fuz, tbh idk, we are studying this on paper.

Comment: @julien1h Try to find out!  It will be very hard to learn assembly if you don't even know what architecture you are programming for.  From the syntax, it could be ARM, but who knows?

Comment: it says .word, they are words not bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARM systems, like most today, are byte addressable.  A 32-bit integer stored in memory occupies 4 bytes.  Each of those 4 bytes has its own byte address.  Thus, in an array of integers, the first integer is at `NUM1` and the second is at `NUM1`+4.  We refer to multi-byte items by just one address — the lowest one among them.  This applies both to 4 byte integers as well as the entire array: we refer to the whole array by its lowest address.

Adding only #1 would be a logic error, as that would not reach the next integer in the array.  If the array had byte or char elements that would be appropriate.

An array holds items of like type, so the scaling necessary for `A[i]` is that `i` is multiplied by the element size, for 4 byte integers, that is 4.

In a structure holding not necessarily like members, we add up the size in bytes of the prior members, plus any alignment padding between elements, to reach the offset of a given structure member.